# Why would you use AWS Elastic Beanstalk in conjunction with AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, elastic-beanstalk

It states here of Elastic Beanstalk and CloudFormation that...

> These services are designed to complement each other.

From my reading, I don't understand why you would want to use them together. The Elastic Beanstalk advantages seem to be nullified by CloudFormation, and vice versa, for example:

- Elastic beanstalk handles resourcing for your application, so why
  would I want to use CloudFormation to specify them?
- Elastic Beanstalk supports single command deployments, however these would not be
  possible if used with CloudFormation
- Elastic Beanstalk allows you to customise the deployment by way of .config files, do .config files work in tandem with CloudFormation templates?
- If I were using CloudFormation to specify my infrastructure, then what advantages
  does Elastic Beanstalk bring to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Elastic beanstalk handles resourcing for your application, so why
>   would I want to use CloudFormation to specify them?

EB can easily take care of a simple web stack with load balancing, application, and db layers. What if your application is more complex than that? What if you need memcache? What if you need multiple application tiers? Etc, etc.

> Elastic Beanstalk supports single command deployments, however these
>   would not be possible if used with CloudFormation

If your needs are simple, then just use EB. If you have more complexity or if you desire more control, use CFN.

> Elastic Beanstalk allows you to customise the deployment by way of
>   .config files, do .config files work in tandem with CloudFormation
>   templates?

Not specifically.

> If I were using CloudFormation to specify my infrastructure, then what
>   advantages does Elastic Beanstalk bring to the table?

Control, flexibility, and ease of adding more layers if needed.